# Python - SQLAlchemy Query

Tags: python, sql, foreign-keys, flask-sqlalchemy

Added Info]

This system is used for storing the voluntary participating information of the students.
I have three modules as follows:

1. student2122: Students' Info storing students' name, student no,
2. voluntary2122: Voluntary activities storing activity name, time , venue...
3. volunteer2121: Recording Students' participating information, such as participants' id, activities' id....

Now I need to show all activities participated by a specific student.

```
class volunteer2122(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "tab_volunteer_2122"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    events_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("tab_voluntary_2122.id"))
    student_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("tab_student_2122.id"))
    actual_hr = db.Column(db.Float(255), default=0)
    student = db.relationship("student2122", back_populates="events")
    event = db.relationship("voluntary2122", back_populates="students")

class voluntary2122(db.Model):
    # voluntary
    __tablename__ = "tab_voluntary_2122"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    v_activity = db.Column(db.String(255),  nullable=False)
    v_date = db.Column(db.Date(), nullable=False, default=None)
    v_time = db.Column(db.String(225), nullable=True)
    v_duration = db.Column(db.Float(255))
    # v_category = db.Column(
    #     db.Enum(CategoryEnum),
    # )
    v_category = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    v_venue = db.Column(db.String(255))
    v_ppl = db.Column(db.String(255))
    v_remark = db.Column(db.String(500))
    students = db.relationship("volunteer2122", back_populates="event")

class student2122(db.Model):
    # student
    __tablename__ = "tab_student_2122"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    cname = db.Column(db.String(255))
    ename = db.Column(db.String(255))
    student_no = db.Column(db.String(255))
    cic_no = db.Column(db.String(255))
    add_date = db.Column(db.String(255))
    class_code = db.Column(db.String(255))
    programme = db.Column(db.String(255))
    campus = db.Column(db.String(255))
    academic_year = db.Column(db.String(255))
    v_hr = db.Column(db.Float(255), default=0)
    v_hr_per = db.Column(db.Float(255), default=0)
    v_cata_hr = db.Column(db.Float(255), default=0)
    v_cata_hr_per = db.Column(db.Float(255), default=0)
    v_catb_hr = db.Column(db.Float(255), default=0)
    v_catb_hr_per = db.Column(db.Float(255), default=0)
    s_hr = db.Column(db.Float(255), default=0)
    s_hr_per = db.Column(db.Float(255), default=0)
    s_cata_hr = db.Column(db.Float(255), default=0)
    s_cata_hr_per = db.Column(db.Float(255), default=0)
    s_catb_hr = db.Column(db.Float(255), default=0)
    s_catb_hr_per = db.Column(db.Float(255), default=0)
    events = db.relationship("volunteer2122", back_populates="student")
```

I would like to show all activities that one specific student has participated with the following html codes:

```
            <tbody class="my-2">
            {% for s in events %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ s.v_activity }}</td>
                <td>{{ s.v_date }}</td>
                <td>{{ s.v_time }}</td>
                <td>{{ s.v_duration }}</td>


            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
```

However, I failed to list the activities and their details with the following route script:

```
@app.route("/v_student_detail/<id>")
def v_student_detail(id):
    student = student2122.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
    done_activities = volunteer2122.query.filter_by(student_id=student.id).all()
    events = voluntary2122.query.filter_by(id=done_activities.events_id).all()
    return render_template('/sv_record/voluntary_record/v_student_detail.html', student=student, events=events)
```

The following error msg. appear once I run the program. And I think I failed in retrieving the activities' information to "events":

The error:
'list' object has no attribute 'events_id'

Would anyone help to advise the solutions? I've spent many time on it and I can not figure it out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`done_activities = volunteer2122.query.filter_by(student_id=student.id).all()` returns a list with all the hits of the query, even 0 hits returns an empty list. Thats why your next line fails

I think you want to do a join. sqlalchemy sometimes is a little more annoying than just plain sql, try something like this:

```
def v_student_detail(id):
    student = student2122.query.filter(student2122.id == id).first()
    events = db.session.query(volunteer2122).join(voluntary2122).filter(volunteer2122.student_id == student.id).all()
    return render_template('/sv_record/voluntary_record/v_student_detail.html', student=student, events=events)
```

Comment: mnzbono, thanks for your help. No error msg any more but it failed to get the voluntary details to "events". The voluntary details are stored in the module "voluntary2122". Anyway, thank you very much.

Comment: sorry, I think I didn't understand the models. Now checking, doesn't ```student.events``` give you the events already? I'll give it another try tomorrow if still not solved

Comment: No. I should say sorry. I haven't made it clear. Have added more information now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

have figured it out with the code shown as follows:

```
        events = db.session.query(voluntary2122).join(volunteer2122, voluntary2122.id==volunteer2122.events_id).filter(volunteer2122.student_id==student.id)
```

But I have another question, see if any could help..thanks a lot.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70095168/combining-two-tables-into-single-table-python-flask-sqlalchemy?noredirect=1#comment123913991_70095168)