# Combining two tables into single table - Python Flask SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, html, for-loop, html-table, flask-sqlalchemy

Knowing that we can use the following code to display the content of the database "events" in table format:

```
            <tbody class="my-2">
            {% for k in events %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ k.v_activity }}</td>
                <td>{{ k.v_date }}</td>
                <td>{{ k.v_time }}</td>
                <td>{{ k.v_duration }}</td>


            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
```

The above table has four columns and the another table as follows displaying the database "done_activities"

```
            <tbody class="my-2">
            {% for s in done_activities %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ s.actual_hr }}</td>

            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
```

**Assuming that these two tables are in correspondent, which means the first row for "events" is related to the first row of "details" and so on.** I would like to display all the above information to the a single table with "five" columns. How could I do that? Would it be necessary to combine these two databases in my python script? I'm new in database handling. Would anyone give a hand to help? Thanks in advance.

Attached below are the model codes, Thanks.

```
class volunteer2122(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "tab_volunteer_2122"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    events_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("tab_voluntary_2122.id"))
    student_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("tab_student_2122.id"))
    actual_hr = db.Column(db.Float(255), default=0)
    student = db.relationship("student2122", back_populates="events")
    event = db.relationship("voluntary2122", back_populates="students")

class voluntary2122(db.Model):
    # voluntary
    __tablename__ = "tab_voluntary_2122"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    v_activity = db.Column(db.String(255),  nullable=False)
    v_date = db.Column(db.Date(), nullable=False, default=None)
    v_time = db.Column(db.String(225), nullable=True)
    v_duration = db.Column(db.Float(255))
    # v_category = db.Column(
    #     db.Enum(CategoryEnum),
    # )
    v_category = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    v_venue = db.Column(db.String(255))
    v_ppl = db.Column(db.String(255))
    v_remark = db.Column(db.String(500))
    students = db.relationship("volunteer2122", back_populates="event")

class student2122(db.Model):
    # student
    __tablename__ = "tab_student_2122"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    cname = db.Column(db.String(255))
    ename = db.Column(db.String(255))
    student_no = db.Column(db.String(255))
    cic_no = db.Column(db.String(255))
    add_date = db.Column(db.String(255))
    class_code = db.Column(db.String(255))
    programme = db.Column(db.String(255))
    campus = db.Column(db.String(255))
    academic_year = db.Column(db.String(255))
    v_hr = db.Column(db.Float(255), default=0)
    v_hr_per = db.Column(db.Float(255), default=0)
    v_cata_hr = db.Column(db.Float(255), default=0)
    v_cata_hr_per = db.Column(db.Float(255), default=0)
    v_catb_hr = db.Column(db.Float(255), default=0)
    v_catb_hr_per = db.Column(db.Float(255), default=0)
    s_hr = db.Column(db.Float(255), default=0)
    s_hr_per = db.Column(db.Float(255), default=0)
    s_cata_hr = db.Column(db.Float(255), default=0)
    s_cata_hr_per = db.Column(db.Float(255), default=0)
    s_catb_hr = db.Column(db.Float(255), default=0)
    s_catb_hr_per = db.Column(db.Float(255), default=0)
    events = db.relationship("volunteer2122", back_populates="student")
```

The first table came from model:voluntary2122 --> events
The second table came from model:volunteer2122 --> done_activities

Route file as follows:

```
        student = student2122.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
        done_activities = volunteer2122.query.filter_by(student_id=student.id).all()
        events = db.session.query(voluntary2122).join(volunteer2122, voluntary2122.id==volunteer2122.events_id).filter(volunteer2122.student_id==student.id)
```

Pl help...

Comment: Can you show your model code? Seems like you need a database JOIN

Comment: Model code added...thanks a lot.

Comment: I see a join in your route file, events should probably have the joined columns of both tables?

Comment: yes, but I don't know how to link them. Now, the "events" in the route file is storing the information from voluntary2122(after querying and filtering codes), but I need to show one column information(actual_hr) that is in volunteer2122. I don't know how to call it together with the information stored in "events" and show them all in the html(single table).

Comment: .join() in your route is the link, try k.actual_hr in your first html, it should work